# filter dataframe by multiple columns after exploding

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

My df contains product names and corresponding information. Relevant here is the name and country sold to:

```
+--------------------+-------------------------+
|        Product_name|collect_set(Countries_en)|
+--------------------+-------------------------+
|                null|     [Belgium,United K...|
|     #5 pecan/almond|                [Belgium]|
| #8 mango/strawberry|                [Belgium]|
|& Sully A Mild Th...|         [Belgium,France]|
|&quot;70CL Liqueu...|         [Belgium,France]|
|&quot;Gingembre&q...|                [Belgium]|
|&quot;Les Schtrou...|         [Belgium,France]|
|&quot;Sho-key&quo...|                [Belgium]|
|&quot;mini Chupa ...|         [Belgium,France]|
|      'S Lands beste|                [Belgium]|
|'T vlierbos confi...|                [Belgium]|
|(H)eat me - Spagh...|                [Belgium]|
|       -cheese flips|                [Belgium]|
|     .soupe cerfeuil|                [Belgium]|
|1 1/2 Minutes Bas...|     [Belgium,Luxembourg]|
|   1/2 Reblochon AOP|                [Belgium]|
|  1/2 nous de jambon|                [Belgium]|
|1/2 tarte cerise ...|                [Belgium]|
|10 Original Knack...|     [Belgium,France,S...|
|    10 pains au lait|         [Belgium,France]|
+--------------------+-------------------------+
```

sample input data:

```
[Row(code=2038002038.0, Product_name='Formula 2 men multi vitaminic', Countries_en='France,Ireland,Italy,Mexico,United States,Argentina-espanol,Armenia-pyсский,Aruba-espanol,Asia-pacific,Australia-english,Austria-deutsch,Azerbaijan-русский,Belarus-pyсский,Belgium-francais,Belgium-nederlands,Bolivia-espanol,Bosnia-i-hercegovina-bosnian,Botswana-english,Brazil-portugues,Bulgaria-български,Cambodia-english,Cambodia-ភាសាខ្មែរ,Canada-english,Canada-francais,Chile-espanol,China-中文,Colombia-espanol,Costa-rica-espanol,Croatia-hrvatski,Cyprus-ελληνικά,Czech-republic-čeština,Denmark-dansk,Ecuador-espanol,El-salvador-espanol,Estonia-eesti,Europe,Finland-suomi,France-francais,Georgia-ქართული,Germany-deutsch,Ghana-english,Greece-ελληνικά,Guatemala-espanol,Honduras-espanol,Hong-kong-粵語,Hungary-magyar,Iceland-islenska,India-english,Indonesia-bahasa-indonesia,Ireland-english,Israel-עברית,Italy-italiano,Jamaica-english,Japan-日本語,Kazakhstan-pyсский,Korea-한국어,Kyrgyzstan-русский,Latvia-latviešu,Lebanon-english,Lesotho-english,Lithuania-lietuvių,Macau-中文,Malaysia-bahasa-melayu,Malaysia-english,Malaysia-中文,Mexico-espanol,Middle-east-africa,Moldova-roman,Mongolia-монгол-хэл,Namibia-english,Netherlands-nederlands,New-zealand-english,Nicaragua-espanol,North-macedonia-македонски-јазик,Norway-norsk,Panama-espanol,Paraguay-espanol,Peru-espanol,Philippines-english,Poland-polski,Portugal-portugues,Puerto-rico-espanol,Republica-dominicana-espanol,Romania-romană,Russia-русский,Serbia-srpski,Singapore-english,Slovak-republic-slovenčina,Slovenia-slovene,South-africa-english,Spain-espanol,Swaziland-english,Sweden-svenska,Switzerland-deutsch,Switzerland-francais,Taiwan-中文,Thailand-ไทย,Trinidad-tobago-english,Turkey-turkce,Ukraine-yкраї́нська,United-kingdom-english,United-states-english,United-states-espanol,Uruguay-espanol,Venezuela-espanol,Vietnam-tiếng-việt,Zambia-english', Traces_en=None, Additives_tags=None, Main_category_en='Vitamins', Image_url='https://static.openfoodfacts.org/images/products/203/800/203/8/front_en.12.400.jpg', Quantity='60 compresse', Packaging_tags='barattolo,tablet', )]
```

Since I want to explore to which countries the products are sold to besides Belgium i split the country column to show every country individually using the code below

```
#create df with grouped products
countriesDF = productsDF\
.select("Product_name", "Countries_en")\
.groupBy("Product_name")\
.agg(F.collect_set("Countries_en").cast("string").alias("Countries"))\
.orderBy("Product_name")

#split df to show countries the product is sold to in a seperate column
countriesDF = countriesDF\
   .where(col("Countries")!="null")\
.select("Product_name",\
        F.split("Countries", ",").alias("Countries"),
        F.posexplode(F.split("Countries", ",")).alias("pos", "val")
    )\
    .drop("val")\
    .select(
        "Product_name",
        F.concat(F.lit("Countries"),F.col("pos").cast("string")).alias("name"),
        F.expr("Countries[pos]").alias("val")
    )\
    .groupBy("Product_name").pivot("name").agg(F.first("val"))\
.show()
```

However, this table now has over 400 columns for countries alone which is not presentable. So my question is:

1. am I doing the splitting / exploding correctly?
2. can I split the df so I get the countries as column names (e.g. 'France' instead of 'countries1' etc.) counting the number of times the product is sold in this country?

Comment: What is your End goal? To compute counts of `Product_name` per country? or you actually want to display this `count( Product_name X COUNTRY)` matrix ?

Comment: The question is - To which countries (besides Belgium) are the products sold to. Since there are so many if looking at the whole df I'm trying to second of your options. So grouped by the product name in the 1st column and and count of the product sold in each country.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some sample data :

```
val sampledf = Seq(("p1","BELGIUM,GERMANY"),("p1","BELGIUM,ITALY"),("p1","GERMANY"),("p2","BELGIUM")).toDF("Product_name","Countries_en")
```

Transform to required df :

```
df = sampledf
.withColumn("country_list",split(col("Countries_en"),","))
.select(col("Product_name"), explode(col("country_list")).as("country"))

+------------+-------+
|Product_name|country|
+------------+-------+
|          p1|BELGIUM|
|          p1|GERMANY|
|          p1|BELGIUM|
|          p1|  ITALY|
|          p1|GERMANY|
|          p2|BELGIUM|
+------------+-------+
```

If you need only counts per country :

```
countDF = df.groupBy("Product_name","country").count()

countDF.show()
+------------+-------+-----+
|Product_name|country|count|
+------------+-------+-----+
|          p1|BELGIUM|    2|
|          p1|GERMANY|    1|
|          p2|BELGIUM|    1|
+------------+-------+-----+
```

Except Belgium :

```
countDF.filter(col("country") =!="BELGIUM").show()

+------------+-------+-----+
|Product_name|country|count|
+------------+-------+-----+
|          p1|GERMANY|    1|
+------------+-------+-----+
```

And if you really want countries as Columns :

```
countDF.groupBy("Product_name").pivot("country").agg(first("count"))

+------------+-------+-------+
|Product_name|BELGIUM|GERMANY|
+------------+-------+-------+
|          p2|      1|   null|
|          p1|      2|      1|
+------------+-------+-------+
```

And you can `.drop("BELGIUM")` to achieve it.

Comment: since the columns 'Countries_en' contains multiple countries like ```|Belgium,France|```
this does no really solve my problem. Also the reason why split this column first

Comment: Can you please post a smaple original input Dataframe in question ?

Comment: @JackSomeone handled the `Belgium,France` part now. Please check

Comment: added a sample. Your addition goes into the right direction I think but when look at the output it county each row as one but not multiple occurances right?

Comment: might it be easier to just get a list of countries =! Belgium?

Comment: It is counting multiple occurrences . Please check 2nd code block carefully and results in 3rd code block. Nothing is getting missed

Answer (score 0):

Final code used:

```
#create df where countries are split off
df = productsDF\
.withColumn("country_list",split(col("Countries_en"),","))\
.select(col("Product_name"), explode(col("country_list")).alias("Country"))\

#create count and filter out Country Belgium, Product Name can be changed as needed
countDF = df.groupBy("Product","Country").count()\
.filter(col("Country") !="Belgium")\
.filter(col('Product') == 'Café').show()
```